# Giving a C# class modular functionalities

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have the class Node that is manipulating instances of my Person class.
The base class with the minimum functionalities looks like this:

```
public class Node
{
    //attributes
    protected readonly int steps;
    protected readonly int angleDeltaQ;

    //constructor
    public Node(int steps, int angleDeltaQ)
    {
        this.steps = steps;
        this.angleDeltaQ = angleDeltaQ;
    }

    //methods
    public virtual int UpdateMe(Person me)
    {
        me.angleQ = QMath.RadLimitQ(me.angleQ + angleDeltaQ);
        me.xQ += QMath.CosQ(me.angleQ, me.speedRev);
        me.zQ += QMath.SinQ(me.angleQ, me.speedRev);
        me.steps--;
        if (me.steps == 0) return (int)NodeFeedback.targetReached;                
        else return (int)NodeFeedback.notFinished;
    }
    public virtual void AssignMe(Person me)
    {
        me.steps = steps << me.speedRev;
    }
}
```

I leave the Person class out of here as it is not important to describe my problem.
What is only needed to know is that Person has a Node attribute and calls the Node's Assign method once, and then Update in a regular manner.

Now there are many additional things the Node might be able to do.

For example at the Update method, it also should change the value of me.yQ. For this it needs additional attributes and needs additional code in the Update method.

For the Person instance it should not matter what exactly is going on with it's Node attribute as long it can call it's two methods.

My problem is now, I have 8 additional features for the Node class. If I would create a subclass of Node for each combination, it would become awfully large.

My question is, is there a tidy way to do this? I plan to have many many instances of Node so I only want it to contain the attributes and methods this specific Node needs.

Comment: Unrelated: _"Because an abstract method declaration provides no actual implementation, there is no method body; the method declaration simply ends with a semicolon and there are no curly braces ({ }) following the signature"_ (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) I would expect this to _not_ compile.

Comment: You are right, please understand the piece of code to get an idea what Node is supposed to do. I forgot to fix the declaration on top of this intention.

Comment: I understand you'll have another class deriving from `Node`. I also understand that what you want may be a "[Decorator Pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern)".

Answer (score 0):

you should use visitor pattern

```
public abstract class Node
{
    //attributes
    protected readonly int steps;
    public readonly int angleDeltaQ;
    private IUpdateVisitor updateVisitor;

    protected  Node():this(new DefaultUpdateVisitor())
    {

    }
    protected  Node(IUpdateVisitor visiter)
    {
        updateVisiter = visiter;
    }
    //constructor
    public Node(int steps, int angleDeltaQ)
    {
        this.steps = steps;
        this.angleDeltaQ = angleDeltaQ;
    }

    //methods
    public virtual int UpdateMe(Person me)
    {
            updateVisitor.UpdateMe(this,me);
    }
    public virtual void AssignMe(Person me)
    {
        me.steps = steps << me.speedRev;
    }
}



public interface IUpdateVisitor
{
     int UpdateMe(Person me);
}


public class DefaultUpdateVisitor : IUpdateVisitor
{
    public  int UpdateMe(Node node, Person me)
    {
        me.angleQ = QMath.RadLimitQ(me.angleQ + node.angleDeltaQ);
        me.xQ += QMath.CosQ(me.angleQ, me.speedRev);
        me.zQ += QMath.SinQ(me.angleQ, me.speedRev);
        me.steps--;
        if (me.steps == 0) return (int)node.NodeFeedback.targetReached;                
        else return (int)node.NodeFeedback.notFinished;
    }
}


public class AotherUpdateVisitor: IUpdateVisitor
{
 public  int UpdateMe(Node node, Person me)
 {
     .....
 }   
}
```

Comment: it is constructor

Comment: Looking at both your suggestion to use visitor pattern and @Fildor 's suggestion to use decorator pattern, it seems like decorator is more suited for my problem. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: Decorate pattern part of structural patterns  category while visiter pattern part of behaviour pattern category.   So if you see your prove is s behaviour problem and not structure problem.